# In Python, I have a class as an attribute of an object. Can I simplify this code?

Tags: python, class, oop

More precisely, I would like to remove the line `self.B = B` in the code below.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        class B:
            def __init__(self):
                self.x = x

        self.B = B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to create a class in `A.__init__` which is directly stored into an instance variable, without first creating a local variable and then assigning that to an instance variable afterwards.

Unfortunately, there's no way to do this if you use the `class` keyword to create the class, because it will always put the created class in the current scope (as a local variable of `A.__init__`).

However, you can technically do this by creating the class dynamically instead, using the three-argument `type` function. I would probably not recommend this though, as it's way less readable.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.B = type("B", (), {"__init__": lambda self: setattr(self, "x", x)})
```

This will also let you specify the name of the class. You could just use `"B"`,  as in the example above, or you could use `"A().B"` or `f"A({x}).B"` or `f"{repr(self)}.B"` or something to make it clearer that `B` is part of an instance of `A`.

Here is a quote from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) explaining what is going on:

> ##### `type(name, bases, dict, **kwds)`
>
> With three arguments, return a new type object. This is essentially a dynamic form of the class statement. The *name* string is the class name and becomes the `__name__` attribute. The *bases* tuple contains the base classes and becomes the `__bases__` attribute; if empty, object, the ultimate base of all classes, is added. The *dict* dictionary contains attribute and method definitions for the class body; it may be copied or wrapped before becoming the `__dict__` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve here. Maybe it's:

```
class A:
    class B:
        def __init__(self, x):
            self.x = x
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.b = A.B(x)

c = A(5)

print(c.b.x)
```